# net core dependencies not recognized on classes but loaded on dependencies folder

Tags: c#, .net-core

I created a solution with three projects ( Domain - Services - UI )the UI project references Domain and Services and did some development already like creating some services and classes, later I change to ( Core - Infrastructure - UI ) when I add the reference to the new projects into my UI project it shows into the dependencies folder but when I try to use services and entity classes from the Core project the system does not find them. Be aware that I removed Domain and Services already.

I already try to reload the project, check that all of them are in the same version of net-core ( 2.2 ) and also run dotnet restore on the UI project.

Comment: This may sound strange, but I've always had problems with .NET Core and .NET Standard on Visual Studio. What helps me usually is restart of visual studio.

Comment: If Fka's suggestion doesn't work: Renaming Projects was always a p.i.a. . There is always some point, where renaming is forgotten. I'd say check that. Everywhere. Even grep the complete source directory tree ... I tend to rather make a new project and import the sources, then adjust namespaces, then delete the old one.

Comment: In addition to Fildors comment; don't forget to look at the .csproj and .sln files. Those should be the first priority. After those you can expand the search.

Comment: Please also specify your Visual Studio version.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2019 community, and also let me clarify that I created two new projects for Core and Infrastructure and imported the files from the old projects and renamed the namespace, then I removed Domain and Services sorry for confusion there.